# User is not successfully created in RedHat

Tags: users, password, useradd, passwd

I'm trying to create a user in RedHat 6.7 but it's not working

`useradd test`Doesn't give any errors, but `/etc/passwd` doesn't have the username

Thus `passwd test`is failing

Comment: when you say failing.. what is the error message ?

Comment: @Kamaraj passwd: Unknown user name 'test'.

Comment: Do this `sudo useradd test; echo $?` and `id test`. Let me know the result.

Comment: @林果皞 useradd: warning: the home directory already exist. Not copying any file from skel directory into it. 0

Comment: @林果皞 id: test: No such user

Comment: I think its pretty clear from output you have to delete the home directory and then run **sudo useradd test**

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra that's not an error, it's a warning

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra I tried that though and it's giving the same output except the warning

Comment: Can you show us the file permission of the file `/etc/passwd` `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group`

Comment: Try `adduser` command instead of `useradd`

Comment: @Mongrel same result

Comment: @Mongrel -rw-r--r-- /etc/passwd. ---------- /etc/shadow. -rw-r--r-- /etc/group.

Comment: Try to add test5 user with `sudo strace -ff -e open useradd test5; echo $?`, ensure you see "/etc/passwd" listed without error. Install `strace` first if no such command.

Comment: What is the Output from `useradd -D` ?

Comment: @Mongrel same thing

Answer (score 1):

Remove any references to test user or group from files:

- /etc/passwd
- /etc/shadow
- /etc/group

then do a **sudo useradd test**

Comment: That didn't work, all files don't have references to the username. I used grep.